# How to change UITableView background color

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have the following codes:

```
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:185/255.0f blue:1 alpha:1];
```

I ended up with this:

[image: result]

The navigation bar did change color as it is supposed to, but the rest of the table view is still plain grey. How do you fix this?

**EDIT:** I scroll my way to the bottom of the table view and it is fine. The search bar on the top comes from a search controller, maybe that is the problem. Here are a picture of the bottom:

[image: bottom of the table view]

Comment: You can change the cell color

Comment: @UmaMadhavi I did change the cell's color, but I want the rest of the grey as showed in the picture to disappear.

Comment: `[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:185/255.0f blue:1 alpha:1]];` has no effect.

Comment: Your links to your pictures are broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the backgroundview of the tableview:

```
UIView* backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
```